# convert pandas string dataframe to int in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a text file with 3 lines :

```
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,5
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.read_fwf("sample.txt",header =None)
df= df.to_numpy()
print("df:",df)
```

running my code gives me a result of 
df:[['1,2,3']['1,2,4']['1,2,5']]

how to convert it to integers?
i want the output to be :

[[1,2,3][1,2,4][1,2,5]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `read_table` method instead of `read_fwf`, which will parse the input as integers for you like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_table("sample.txt", sep = ',', header = None)
df = df.to_numpy()
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 4]
 [1, 2, 5]]
```

Comment: thanks for the method but its still gives me this output:       df: [[1 2 3]
 [1 2 4]
 [1 2 5]]
[Finished in 0.5s] i cant separate it with comma

Comment: That is correct, the commas are mainly for visual purposes, numpy arrays do not need them. You can confirm by checking the values in the array by accessing them and you should notice that df[0][0] = 1, df[0][1] = 2, df[0][2] = 3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_table("sample.txt", sep = ',', header = None)
df = df.to_numpy()
df=np.copy(df)
df=df.tolist()

print("df:",df)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 4]
 [1, 2, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
df = [[int(value) for value in re.findall('\d+',each[0])] for each in df]
```

**Explanation:**

Using nested list comprehension, we access each list using 'each'. Taking the 1st element only as each list consist of one element i.e a string like '1,2,3', using regex, find all digits present and store them as list of lists in 'df'